# Can't serialize using DataContractSerializer

Tags: wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

**I have tried the following code:**

```
PolicyProcessRequest.BranchCode = "HeadOff"
PolicyProcessRequest.Policy.BranchCode = "HeadOff"
PolicyProcessRequest.Policy.Risks.Item(0).BranchCode = "HeadOff"

Dim dcs As DataContractSerializer = New DataContractSerializer(GetType(PureMessagingService.PolicyProcessRequestType))

Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
dcs.WriteObject(ms, PolicyProcessRequest)
```

Am getting the following exception on the call to WriteObject

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException was caught
>
> HResult=-2146233076  Message=Member BranchCode in type Sirius.SBO.Import.PureMessagingService.BaseRequestType cannot be serialized.
>   This exception is usually caused by trying to use a null value where a null value is not allowed.
>
> The 'BranchCode' member is set to its default value (usually null or zero). The member's EmitDefault setting is 'false', indicating that the member should not be serialized.
>
> However, the member's IsRequired setting is 'true', indicating that it must be serialized. This conflict cannot be resolved.  Consider setting 'BranchCode' to a non-default value. Alternatively, you can change the EmitDefaultValue property on the DataMemberAttribute attribute to true, or changing the IsRequired property to false.

Yet I've set the 'BranchCode' property to the non default value everywhere in the request.

```
Public Class BaseNBQuoteRequestType

        Private agentCodeField As String

        Private branchCodeField As String

        Private currencyCodeField As CurrencyType

        Private currencyCodeFieldSpecified As Boolean

        Private itemField As BasePartyType

        Private policyField As BaseQuoteRiskMsgType

        Private updatePartyField As Boolean

        Public Property AgentCode() As String
            Get
                Return Me.agentCodeField
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me.agentCodeField = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property BranchCode() As String
            Get
                Return Me.branchCodeField
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me.branchCodeField = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property CurrencyCode() As CurrencyType
            Get
                Return Me.currencyCodeField
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As CurrencyType)
                Me.currencyCodeField = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property CurrencyCodeSpecified() As Boolean
            Get
                Return Me.currencyCodeFieldSpecified
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
                Me.currencyCodeFieldSpecified = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Party() As BasePartyType
            Get
                Return Me.itemField
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As BasePartyType)
                Me.itemField = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Policy() As BaseQuoteRiskMsgType
            Get
                Return Me.policyField
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As BaseQuoteRiskMsgType)
                Me.policyField = value
            End Set
        End Property

    Public Property UpdateParty() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.updatePartyField
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me.updatePartyField = value
        End Set
        End Property
    End Class
```

Comment: can you show us the PolicyProcessRequestType class ?

Comment: Added class definition to original message.

Comment: it's BaseNBQuoteRequestType class not PolicyProcessRequestType class

Comment: Public Class PolicyProcessRequestType
        Inherits BaseNBQuoteRequestType
    End Class

Comment: without any specificities ?

Comment: something is missing. Exception message suggests there is a mismatch  between datamember definition and member values. I can not see datamember here.

Comment: I've temporarily worked around by setting EmitDefaultValue to True,  <System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired:=True, EmitDefaultValue:=True)> _
        Public Property BranchCode() As String

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and it comes from the DataContractSerializer which is used to generate the code.  I have other services which use the XmlSerializer with no problem.

Unfortunatly, when using Svcutil.exe or the 'Add Service Reference' feature in Visual Studio to generate client code, an appropriate serializer is automatically selected for you. If the schema is not compatible with the DataContractSerializer, the XmlSerializer is selected ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901(v=vs.110).aspx)).

So, you have to manualy fix the IsRequired setting in references.cs each time you generate it.

Replace

```
IsRequired=true
```

by

```
IsRequired=false
```

in the references.cs file.